# Closing the question: Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm

Tags: discussion

I must confess I'm irritated regarding the behavior of some guys here. [My question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1534/409) has been closed, but mentioned reasons seem somewhat weak.

Yes, what I found based on a hoax. But is this an argument to close a question? It **is** a question (respectively missing knowledge) regarding the German language and I **learned** something from the answer. I think this legitimates this to be here.

[Joel Spolsky](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) wrote in his blog about the goals of StackExchange:

> Make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your
>   questions

Does someone makes this a better place by closing (or deleting) this? Is it not possible, that others read the same hoax and are glad to learn something? Shall I start laughing about the missing knowledge or mistakes of all others here?

Regarding our own [FAQ](https://german.stackexchange.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face.

Wasn't this mistake a problem that I face? Yes!
Is it answerable? Yes!
Is this chatty or open-ended? No!

@userunknown:

> We laughed - now let's delete it.

**Insolet**! Shall I lough about your questions or your problems?

@Em1:

> Mir fällt gerade erst auf, dass die Überschrift eine Frage nach der
>   Herkunft andeutet, während im Text nach der Bedeutung gefragt wird. -
>   Ebenfalls für close gevoted. Imho muss diese Frage anschließend sogar
>   gelöscht werden.

Ok I corrected this. But you can see my intention out of my question and the answer from splattne. You have enough reputation to edit the question.

I already wondered about the harsh tone as I wrote this. This has now culminated.

@all:
If someone asks a question, this person wants to learn something or validate his knowledge. Others answer to this and share their knowledge. This is a simple principle. If you start laughing about the persons that ask, at sometime they are not going to ask you anymore and this will become a very lonely place. Take care of our own etiquette!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aus Faulheitsgründen antworte ich mal kurz in Deutsch:

In der ersten Ausführung klang diese Frage eher nach ner Dummy-Frage. Getreu dem Motto, ich will irgenwas fragen, habe nur leider keine. (persönlicher Eindruck!)

> **Herkunft von „Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm“**
>
> Irgendwo in den Tiefen des Internet entdeckte ich die Herkunftserklärung zu dem bekannten Sprichwort:
>
> > Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm.
>
> Diese Erklärung war irgendwie vollkommen anders, als das, was ich irgendwann mal dazu gelernt hatte. Was meint ihr, was dieses Sprichwort bedeutet?
>   Was ich selber dazu gefunden habe, poste ich mit etwas Abstand zu dieser Frage.

Also, Titel der Frage = Es geht um die Herkunft. Der erste Satz stellt heraus, du hast die Herkunft schon gefunden. Dann sagst du, die Herkunft ist aber widersprüchlich mit dem, was du bisher wusstest und fragst dann aber: "Was bedeutet dieses Sprichwort".

JA, ich kann das korrigieren, nur weiß ich nicht WAS die eigentlich Frage ist. Bist du dir unsicher geworden, aufgrund der "neuen Herkunft", dass du das Sprichwort richtig verstanden hast? Oder wolltest du doch nur sicherstellen, was die eigentliche Herkunft ist? Betrachtet man das Sprichwort mal mit eigenen Augen, fällt einem auf, dass die figurative Erklärung offensichtlich ist. Eine "historische Geschichte" (*hust*) um irgendwelche Zwillinge ist - für jemanden der diese Story versteht (und du sprichst Deutsch) - augenscheinlich falsch. Also kann das nicht wirklich deine Frage sein.

Du hast die Frage jetzt so abgeändert, dass sie nur nach der Herkunft fragt, aber das glaube ich dir immer noch nicht.

Du hättest die Frage aber ganz einfach anders formulieren können. Zum Beispiel:

> **Herkunft von "Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm"**
>
> Ich habe mir Gedanken über die Herkunft des Sprichwortes gemacht, leider fand ich im Internet aber nur eine unglaubwürdige Geschichte (LINK).
>
> Ich denke, dass das Sprichwort so gemeint ist, dass bla bla bla und bekanntlich bleibt ein Apfel ja tatsächlich in der Nähe des Baum(stammes) liegen.
>
> Wisst ihr, wer dieses Sprichwort als Erstes gesagt/geschrieben hat und ob er es auch tatsächlich so gemeint hat?

Stattdessen - und das ist letztlich der Grund, warum ich überhaupt keine Sekunden darüber nachgedacht habe, die Frage zu verbessern - postest du sogar als Abschlusssatz, dass du die mysteriöse Geschichte später posten möchtest (was du nie getan hast ;)).

- Jeder googled sowieso und trifft nach zwei Minuten auf die Geschichte.
- Das klingt eher wie ein Spiel.
- Der oben genannte Widerspruch (Herkunft/Bedeutung) stellt die Intention der Frage ins Abseits

  --> Die Frage gehört geclosed.

Sorry, falls der Ton hier und da etwas harsch klingt. Ist nicht persönlich gemeint. Ich weiß nicht, was du dir damals wirklich gedacht hast, als du die Frage gestellt hast. Ich kann dir nur sagen, wie die Frage wirkt.

Comment: +1 denn diese Antwort klingt fair und sachlich. Damit kann ich mehr als gut leben. Danke!

Comment: Ich habe die Frage entsprechend überarbeitet. Ich hoffe so wird es nun besser sein.

Answer (score 1):

I conclude with Em1: To tell us, that there are 2 concurrent explanations for the saying, without telling us which, makes it look like a quizzle.

We didn't even knew what you have found, and what, in contrast, you believe.

Last year you asked the question, but didn't react to the comments in June 2011. This year it popped again up, I saw that nobody made an attempt to defend the question and to react to our questions, not even to confirm, that the hoax splattne immediately found is the explanation in question, so I made the suggestion to close it.

If there is a serious question, which is worth answering, than whether the whole site with this example is a hoax.

Comment: I have (almost) believed. I have felt ashamed. It was a time when I was barely here. Overall: Yes, a bad question. My criticism, however, regarding your person was your comment that was simply below the belt.

Comment: My comment was made with the assumption, that you tried to make a funny question for entertainment purpose, which didn't work out, and that we laugh *with* you, not *about* you. Would you read this as an insult (insolet?) too?

Comment: Everything is ok. In my opinion we can close this chapter. Thanks for your comment. It's a nice point of view and I can perfectly life with this.

Comment: @Markus: Fine. I'm sorry that we had this misunderstanding.