# What efforts should we take before we close a question?

Tags: discussion

The ongoing meta discussion on this question:

- [Closing the question: Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/closing-the-question-der-apfel-fallt-nicht-weit-vom-stamm)

and also close votes and discussions in comments to this question:

- https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4794/letztendlich-letztlich-am-ende-des-tages-annoying-or-modern-german

made me wonder if it was a better idea to put more effort in improving questions (and answers) rather than in downvoting or closing.

In both examples only minor edits that were already suggested would significantly improve the question and thus help to make GL&U better.

Why don't we just go ahead and edit, or at least give the OP a chance to do so by themselves before we cast our votes?

Comment: Die Frage bzgl. Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm ist ein Jahr alt. Es wurde durchaus schon Kritik vor einem Jahr geäußert und noch mal im Februar. Für OP genug Zeit um die Frage ausreichend zu verbessern. Dies ist erst jetzt nachdem sie geschlossen wurde geschehen.

Answer (score 2):

Bzgl. der Votes: Wir sind hier auf GLU noch sehr human, wenn man das mit anderen SE-Seiten vergleicht. Dort werden teilweise Fragen von Moderatoren geschlossen (mit nur einer Stimme), die von anderen gleichzeitig upgevotet wurden.

Da wir hier grundsätzlich 5 Stimmen brauchen, kann getrost jeder eine Frage closevoten, wenn die Frage einen Mangel an Qualität aufweist, der **ausschließlich** vom OP korrigiert werden kann. Das ist imho in beiden Fragen gegeben. Wenn die Frage geschlossen wurde, kann sie ja immer noch verbessert und wieder geöffnet werden.

Comment: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/325/please-use-english-on-the-meta-site

Answer (score 1):

Mit den Downvotes ist das so ne Sache. Ich kann eine Frage kommentieren, zwei Tage warten was passiert und dann downvoten. Wenn die Frage dann aber untergeht (OK, auf GLU aufgrund der aktuell geringen Aktivität unwahrscheinlich), kann der Downvote vergessen werden.

Daher würde ich sagen, downvoten und kommentieren und wenn dann die Frage verbessert wird, den Downvote entfernen. So zumindest habe ich auch das System von Anfang an verstanden und so wird es auch auf anderen Seiten praktiziert.

Comment: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/325/please-use-english-on-the-meta-site

Answer (score 1):

There is a serious difference in closing a question and in downvoting it:

If we close a question, no (further) answers are possible.

I think this is the way to go if the direction of the question, its meaning, is unclear. It might else receive answers which are valuable, but off topic, since the question is unclear. Those answers might receive upvotes, which makes it hard to change the question later, when the person, who asked it, reacts.

Closing a question means to enforce a reaction. Else it is preparation to delete it.

Downvoting can be "shows no research effort" while the question is pretty clear.

Both reactions can and should be reversed, if the reason to do so is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Bzgl. Korrigieren: Soweit es im Rahmen unserer Möglichkeiten ist, sollten wir die Fragen korrigieren; und das machen wir auch schon immer so.

Es gab schon oft genug Korrekturen und Verbesserungen, die weit über das Korrigieren von Fehlern hinausgehen. Es gab z.B. schon komplette Umformulierungen, die auch akzeptiert worden.

Problematisch ist es meines Erachtens aber, wenn die Intention vom OP nur schwer zu erkennen ist, eine Frage sehr kompliziert ist (z.B. [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4515/1224), welche viele Korrekturen über sich ergehen lassen musste) oder aus irgendwelchen anderen Gründen es schwer ist, die Frage sinnvoll zu korrigieren. Dann sollte keiner von uns anfangen ins Blaue zu raten.

Das bedeutet, dass das Verfahren, wie wir es zur Zeit anwenden vollkommen OK ist. Eventuell müssen wir noch einige Leute motivieren, mehr zu korrigieren; aber wir haben bereits eine Handvoll Leute, die sich dafür sehr wohl berufen fühlen.

Die betroffenen Fragen sind aus verschiedenen Gründen schwer zu verbessern; auch wenn es zumindest im Falle der Apfel-Frage recht leicht ist eine gute Frage zu formulieren (ein Beispiel habe ich im entsprechenden meta Thread geposetet). Aber imho sollte alle Korrekturen, die nicht vom OP gemacht werden, in keiner Weise die Intention einer Frage verändern! (Diese dürfen aber vorgeschlagen werden, so dass der OP - wenn er zustimmt - die Möglichkeit hat, dies selbst zu machen)

Comment: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/325/please-use-english-on-the-meta-site