# How to deal with a user who misbehaves? And what if his offence is below the belt?

Tags: discussion

The moderators should decide whether to name the user or not. For the following let us name him "user X".

User X:

> We laughed - now let's delete it.

Very good reaction of the offended user (I did the highlights):

> Insolet! Shall I lough about your questions or your problems?
>
> ...
>   I already wondered about the harsh tone as I wrote this. **This has now culminated**.
>
> @all: If someone asks a question, this person wants to **learn something** or **validate his knowledge**. Others answer to this and share their knowledge. This is a simple principle. If you start laughing about the persons that ask, at sometime **they are not going to ask you anymore** and this will become a **very lonely place**. **Take care of our own etiquette!**

Comment from offended user:

> I have (almost) believed. I have felt ashamed. It was a time when I was barely here. Overall: Yes, a bad question. My criticism, however, **regarding your person was your comment that was simply below the belt**.

User X gave **no excuse** until today!

Because a lot of **flags** (from other users and me, see also question [comments-flags-and-etiquette](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/comments-flags-and-etiquette)) the most bad comments have vanished from this side. Good for new users to get no poor impression of this web side, too late for earlier users ...

How to deal with such a (over long time) misbehaving (dogmatic, pedantic, petty, polemic,  insulting, educating other people, systematic downvoting) user? He is told from users to be misbehaving more than one time! (another message about misbehaving of user X in German: "Ich kenne Deine Beweggründe ("Deine Sache") nicht, aber ich fühle mich von der **polemischen Art und Weise abgestoßen**.")

I think it is **high time** to educate him.

**Is a official warning enough or better exclusion?**

Because the misbehavior is constantly (and how long will he respect the warning?) and no excuse **I vote for exclusion**.

See also the question [does-careless-voting-or-non-voting-damage-this-site](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/does-careless-voting-or-non-voting-damage-this-site)!

Comment: Ich bin vielleicht etwas spät dran, da ich mit Abwesenheit geglänzt habe, aber ich habe mal einen Closevote hier erteilt. Die Diskussionen, so erscheint es mir beim Überblick, sind nicht gerade zielsuchend geführt worden und ich würde es begrüßen, wenn dieser Thread hier nicht in Zukunft für weitere Streiteren missbraucht wird. - Auch wenn ich mir bewusst bin, dass mein Close-Vote der einzige bleiben wird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ich bin mir meines Englisch nicht so sicher, deshalb schreibe ich hier in Deutsch. Falls nötig, könnte einer der Moderatoren es bitte übersetzen?

Du, user unknown, hast Dir durch Deine (von Dir missverstandene) Art zu Downvoten und durch deine Art, wie Du Deine Fragen, Antworten und Kommentare formulierst über einen langen Zeitraum einen berechtigt schlimmen Ruf erworben, dessen Auswirkung ich schwer abschätzen kann (es scheinen einige deshalb German den Rücken gekehrt zu haben; **300 auf Grund von Flaggs gelöschte Komentare von Dir belegen, woher dein Ruf kommt**.). Die von mir aufgezeigte Aktion von Dir war nur **das letzte Glied in einer langen Kette**, die jeder im Chat, in Meta und in Deinen Fragen, Antworten und Kommentaren nachvollziehen kann, wenn er einen Blick hineinwirft.

Trotzdem Dir mehrfach klar signalisiert wurde, dass **Dein Benehmen ungehörig ist oder als ungehörig empfunden wird**, hast Du auf Deinem (für die anderen nicht nachvollziehbaren) Standpunkt **beharrt** und in **keinster Weise** darauf mit einer Änderung Deiner Handlungsweise reagiert. Weder geantwortet noch sich entschuldigt (siehe zitierten Fall).

**Und nun wunderst Du Dich, woher Dein schlechter Ruf kommt?**

Wenn ich einen Hinweis bekomme, dass ich mich zu einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt daneben benommen habe, breche ich mir keinen Zacken aus der Krone, diesen Hinweis ernst zu nehmen. Wenn dann nicht nur eine Person mir signalisiert, dass mein Verhalten falsch war, bleiben eigentlich nur zwei Möglichkeiten übrig:

- **Ich nehme den Hinweis ernst**, berücksichtige ihn und ändere mein Verhalten, auch wenn ich persönlich mein Verhalten nicht so einschätze. In der Regel halten mir dann Freunde einen Spiegel vor die Augen, um mich auf einen Fehler freundlich und respektvoll aufmerksam zu machen.
- **Ich ignoriere den und die Hinweise**. Das steht jedem frei, dann aber sollte derjenige erkennen, dass er nicht in diese Gemeinschaft passt und sie von sich aus verlassen.

Ich erkenne in Deinem Verhalten eigentlich nur eines ganz klar:

> §1: User unknown hat immer Recht.
>
> §2: Sollte user unknown einmal nicht Recht haben, tritt automatisch §1 in Kraft.

So hast Du bestimmte Maschen entwickelt, die hier deutlich zum Tragen kommen:

1. Nur was user unknown meint ist richtig. (siehe die vielen Zurechtweisungen in Deinen Fragen mit fett hervorgehobenen Sätzen; kommt Dir zufällig etwas bekannt vor?)
2. Stimmt jemand mit user unknowns persönlichen Meinung nicht überein, wird er niedergemacht, sei es mit Downvoting oder entsprechenden (z. B. harschen, provozierenden, beleidigenden, ...) Kommentaren. Wenn auf seine Kommenatre nicht reagiert wird, wird downgevotet. Merke: User unknown darf nicht reagieren (Siehe Nichtantwort auf den Hinweis auf seine Beleidigung; siehe Masche 6).
3. Sollte das Opfer sich wehren, versucht user unknown ihn in ellenlange Diskussionen zu verstricken und letztlich totzureden.
4. Auf Fragen, die unangehm sind, wird nicht geantwortet. Statt dessen werden schnell 3 weitere aufgeworfen und die unangenehme schnell vergessen ...
5. Zitate werden aus dem Zusammenhang gerissen, um zu den eigenen Zwecken zu passen ...
6. Es wird mit unterschiedlichem Maß gemessen: was user unknown darf, dürfen andere nicht.

Mir gegenüber befindest Du Dich gerade in Masche 3 (ellenlange Diskussion), garniert mit Masche 4 und 5, und ich werde Dir keine weitere Plattform für Dein Fehlverhalten bieten.

Für Dich stellt sich nur eine Frage:

> Wirst Du Dein Verhalten ändern und wenigstens hier respektvoll und vernünftig mit den Menschen umgehen? Dazu gehören keine harschen Kommentare mehr, kein ungerechtfertigtes Downvoting (siehe entsprechende Frage hier in Meta) und verlerne ganz schnell die Maschen...

**Es gibt aus meiner Sicht keinen Grund, diese Diskussion weiterzuführen, alles Wesentliche ist bereits gesagt.**

Da Du weder Dein Verhalten ändern wirst (solche Menschen nenne ich "beratungsresistent") noch Dich entschuldigen wirst bleibe ich bei meiner Forderung: **Ausschluss**.

In der Hoffnung, das Dein Ausschluß **absolut klarmacht**, dass wir, die Gemeinschaft hier, einen **respektvollen, freundlichen Umgang mit Menschen** neben der Pflege der Deutschen Sprache wollen und wir auch **bereit sind**, dafür **aktiv** zu werden.

**Ende der Diskussion.**

Comment: Leute, die nochmal gehörig austeilen, und sich dann zum Schiedsrichter aufschwingen, obwohl sie Partei sind, sind mir die liebsten. Die einzig glaubwürdige Methode eine Diskussion zu beenden ist die, dass man nicht diskutiert; oder die Chinamethode, natürlich. Du bezichtigst mich erneut des Beleidigens ohne jeden Beleg, Du versuchst mir das Wort zu verbieten, in dem Du jede Verteidigung meinerseits als §1-und-2 - Variante vorab diffamierst. Nachdem Du Dich selbst gerühmt hast Du hättest `mir das Maul gestopft` beschwörst Du, wie überlegt Du mit Kritik umgingst. **Hör auf mich zu mobben.**

Comment: @userunknown: Kannst Du nun nachvollziehen, wie sich Deine "Gesprächsparter" gefühlt haben? Hoffentlich ...

Comment: Wie gesagt - ich habe niemanden beleidigt. Ich bin auf Deine mannigfachen, unsubstantiierten Vorwürfe detailliert eingegangen und habe als Reaktion einsilbige Richtersprüche der Art: "Didn't confess - now ban him!" erfahren. Du wirst persönlich und wirfst mir vor, polemisch zu sein, bist es aber nicht minder. Im Gegenteil, denn bei Dir beschränken sich Vorwürfe auf das Allgemeine. Welche Gesprächspartner meinst Du konkret? Ich glaube nicht, dass Dein Verhalten mit meinem vergleichbar ist. Ich habe niemanden gemobbt.

Comment: Dem ist leider nicht so -- es kommt überhaupt nicht darauf an, was Du in diesem Fall von Deinen Aktionen **denkst**, es kommt darauf an, dass Du vielfach andere gemobbt hast - auch wenn **Du es für Dich anders definierst**. Du hast mehrfach eine Rückmeldung erhalten, dass Dein Verhalten **unbotmäßig** ist und hast Dir die vornehme Freiheit genommen, darauf zu schweigen. Jetzt erst, nachdem Dir ein Spiegel vorhgehalten worden ist, der Dir das antun, was Du den anderen angetan hast (denk an die geflaggten Kommentare!), jetzt auf einmal mißt Du mit verschiedenem Maß: Du darfst das, andere nicht.

Comment: @userunknown: Wie war das mit dem User, der **wegen Dir** seinen Account gelöscht hat? Ändere ganz dringend Deine Sichtweise: Wenn Du mehrfach die Rückmeldung bekommst, Dich unbotmäßig zu benehmen (**unabhängig davon, ob Du das für richtig hälst oder nicht**) und nicht reagierst, ja sogar das gleiche Verhalten zeigst, nennst Du nicht **mobben? Was dann? Freundlich liebhaben?** Mach Dich nicht lächerlich! So geht Dein Verhalten nicht weiter. Entweder Du änderst Dich und wirst freundlich zu den Leuten oder geh. Du bist die Ursache, dass hier kein Berieb mehr ist!

Comment: @userunknown: Und dass Du mich wieder ungerechtfertigt downgevoted hast, weil ich wohl Deinen Kommentar nicht beachtet habe, habe ich geflaggt. Du änderst Dein Verhalten nicht: **Ausschluß**.

Comment: @Userunknown: Und ehrlich, mir bringt die Diskussion nicht, **ich hoffe eigentlich nur, dass Du versteht, wie falsch Du Deine Wirkung auf die Leute hier einschätzt** und dass Deine massive Unfreundlichkeit massivste Auswirkungen auf neue Besucher hat, die mit völligem Recht keinen Grund sehen müssen, hier zu bleiben, wenn einer meint, das Recht und die heilige Pflicht zu haben, **hier alle runter zu machen und ihnen seinen Willen aufzuzwingen**. Ich nenne das Terror ... Du magst das nicht so sehen, aber viele andere sehen das hier so. **Was zählt dann in einer Gemeinschaft?**

Comment: @userunknown: zu deinem Downvote meiner Antwort bei [was-haut-man-in-die-fresse](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5486/was-haut-man-in-die-fresse): Willst Du mir wirklich sagen, jemand sagt  "Hau ihm eine Hand in die Fresse"? Wirklich? "Hau ihm eine Hand in das Gesicht" klingt nicht so falsch, obwohl man dann eher "ihm eine Ohrfeige gibt" oder "Ihm eine Backpfeife verpaßt" sagen würde. Machst Du dich da mit deinem Downvote nicht lächerlich? Lösch deinen falschen Kommentar und mach den Downvote wieder rückgängig!

Comment: Wenn sich jemand gemobbt gefühlt hätte, dann hätte er sich beschweren können. Du wiederholst hier pauschal Vorwürfe, und auf meine Nachfrage, das zu konkretisieren kommt nichts. Welcher User hat sich wegen mir gelöscht? Hast Du dafür Belege? Im Chat hast Du behauptet, dass mein Up-Downvote-Quotient 1:1 sei, und dass Du das nachgeschaut hättest. Die Wahrheit ist, dass das Verhältnis 3:1 ist. Wo habe ich Rückmeldung erhalten, dass ich andere gemobbt hätte? Wo sind die Belege? Du bleibst sie schuldig. Ich sage: Wenn sich niemand bei mir beschwert hat, dann kann es ja so klar nicht gewesen sein.

Comment: Du bleibst die Belege schuldig, weil Du keine Belege hast. Und Du hast keine Belege, weil es keine gibt. Du findest kein Mobbing von mir und keine Beleidigungen. Ich meine, Du hast die Abwertungen gegen Deine Beiträge persönlich genommen statt als Kritik an den Antworten, und dann gesucht ob Du den weißen Ritter für einen Dritten spielen kannst, damit es nicht so offensichtlich ist. http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/439/266 Was hat es mit markierten Kommentaren auf sich? Ich weiß nicht, welche Kommentare Du markiert hast - Du hast wieder nichts belegt. Man wird nicht informiert über ...

Comment: ... markierte Kommentare - es ist wirklich keine böse Absicht von mir. Was soll ich sagen zu unbekannten Kommentaren von mir? Gib mal Butter bei die Fische - am besten im Chat, hier ufert es aus. Der jüngste Thread ist hier m.E. off topic. Du kannst sachlich einen Kommentar dort verfassen, oder einen eigenen Metathread eröffnen, aber nicht alles auf einmal und durcheinander.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6393/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-kurt)

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for bringing up the topic. It's not only important for this single case. *Acting respectfully* to people who participate is a core value of our community.

Regarding "warning or exclusion", I think exclusion mustn't ("darf nicht") be the first step in moderation. In this specific I'll try to contact the accused user by email and ask if he/she could comment on this issue. Both sides have to be heard.

I suspect that some users don't see that their "style" ("Wortwahl") is discouraging other people.

Let's *try* to resolve this problem not by excluding somebody, but let's see if we can align users to respect each other. Sometimes it's only a matter of awareness. If the situation doesn't get better, we still can reevaluate what steps are necessary.

Comment: The problem is more that he is not only discouraging other people with his "style", he is offending them and too often below the belt. And for a long time he showed no changing of this behavior nor he is willing to learn that his kind of style is wrong here. I can't see a respectful acting from him.

Comment: Additional have a look on his continuing downvoting tours, see for example his comment "User y said xyz is not ment" and downvoting (nearly? not sure, I think all) all given answers. For me this is a downvoting tour for personal pedantic reasons without a carefuly reading and thinking about the question. This is absolutly not acceptable and shows no respect for other people. Especially because the given answers offers more than only xyz he criticized.

Comment: Sorry my English, I say it in German: Ohne **angemessene** Entschuldigung**en** und Rücknahme der unberechtigten Downvotingtour**en** bleibe ich beim Ausschluß.

Comment: To awareness you said: First of all User X needs a lot of self-awareness (German: Selbsterkenntnis) to be able to reduce his misbehavior. He can or want not to see that his rude style ("Wortwahl") is not funny nor sarcastic, it lacks every humor and is only offending others. And I saw in all causes where he is told to be rude **not only one excuse** for **more than one year** now ... In German I call that "beratungsresistent".

Comment: Erneute Downvoting-Tour und reizende Kommentar-Ergüsse von User X. Treibt er nicht schon lange genug sein terrorisierendes Unwesen hier? Was muß noch alles passieren, bis ihm ein Riegel vorgeschoben wird? Nur noch er alleine auf der Seite? Wie war das: "very lonely place"? Wie lange soll ihm hier noch eine Plattform für sein unflätiges Verhalten geboten werden? Ganz zu schweigen davon, dass er nicht einmal Stellung beziehen kann ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my view on this matter:

We as a community are by definition a heterogenous group of people who share only one common interest: the German language. This of course is a wide field and we may have different views of what we mean by that.

There may be people who would love to see this site as an excellent scientific resource for professional linguists or for Germanists. At the other end of the spectrum there are people who only just started learning German and thus may ask questions far off the scientific scope. It is my strong believe that we need to be a good place to ask for all those people. This is even more so as the scientific end of the spectrum is not really much represented here. Therefore I don't mind easy to answer basic questions as much as I love to see questions that deal with complicated or even disputed aspects of our language.

This is not so for all of us. I do know that there are quite a few people who put considerable effort into making the site better in the sense of scientifically good content. They contribute with answers, comments, votes and downvotes. **This is how it should be.**

Everybody knows that I have a different view when it comes to downvoting or writing harsh comments on questions that may not meet a certain (still to be defined) standard. But this is my own personal view  which I made clear in several meta posts here. Still, I can live with downvotes for too easy or too sloppy questions or answers. This is the essence of our community where people will always have different views.

But there is a more concerning issue I see. It is the problem of different language skills either from people's native language, resp. foreign language, or coming from their different social completence when writing posts or comments here. We also need quite a bit of tolerance here to avoid misunderstandings and to not feel bad. User unknown made a good point when he says:

> Ich meine, Du hast die Abwertungen gegen Deine Beiträge persönlich genommen statt als Kritik an den Antworten [...]

In this case there was a communication problem when comments intended to refer to content where taken personally. This happens a lot. But we will not be able to stop that. People will always have a different level of sensibility.

We all should point to ambiguous, easily misinterpretated posts and comments and help to clarifying them.

But we want the wide spectrum of different opinions here. **They are welcome.** Banning a user X who has a different view from user Y is counterproductive and should be reserved to extreme cases only.

#### I do not see anybody here who is such an extreme case. Therefore I do not see any need to discuss a ban.

But I'd love to see all those users *"X"* (they are not a single person) to think twice before they write comments or cast their votes to help avoiding unneccessary irritations.

Comment: You are right that we need tolerance here, but I can't see any tolerance of user unknown. I'm not angry, that he downvoted me, I just dislike that he is wrong and so the downvote is not okay. He did the same with a lot of other people here. That's the problem. His kind of downvoting all people here is the problem and damages this site. Not more, not less.

Comment: I agree 100% with you, Takkat. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: @user1955 In a democracy, the reasons for a vote (or in this case, downvote) are all the voter's own. There is not law against voting for the wrong reasons. Voting is not about who is right, but about what we want to support. If one user does not want to support the right answer, than that is his legitimate choice. Often, the best answers aren't those with the highest votes anyway, especially when new and better answers arrive after questions have dropped from the front page.

Comment: @Takkat I'm all for you answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a public place.

When you go to the train station, you'll see all kinds of people there. Homeless people sleep on the benches in the park in front of it. Punks linger on the stairs and ask passers-by for money. Unwashed mentally ill sit opposite you in the train and talk to you despite the fact that you keep staring at the newspaper. Drunk teenagers listen to loud music and put their shoes on the seats.

None of this is what you would create for yourself if you had the opportunity (or, depending on who you are, you might have the whole train full of noisy teens or rebelling punks), but in a community these people have to be allowed their place. We're a liberal, non-totalitarian culture and proud of it, and we have to live with people choosing different lifestyles.

Especially, a community has to be tolerant of not everyone living a stress free life and constantly being in a good mood. Because, let's be realistic: Why are we here? Some of us spend a lot of time in the internet, because they find it difficult to make friends in "real life". Some of us spend time here to relax a few minutes from a stressful job. I'm here, because I don't want to study for my next exam. The books are all around me and press on my mind and put me in a bad mood.

And with this pressure on my mind, with, maybe, the dissappointment of my wife having left me a year ago and the continuing emotional exhaustion that having to deal with her over our child brings, with all this I read and write in this community. Sometimes my private frustration and anger spill over in my answers. Sometimes I'm more easily irritated and downvote someone because he wasn't as enthusiastic about my answer as I wished for, because the votes boost my self-confidence.

None of the above is true (I'm not divorced), I just wanted to illustrate a situation where a perfectly nice person might find himself acting here in the wrong way. Friendliness is a goal, but it is not a law, and it is impossible for most of us to be friendly at all times.

For me, a community like stackexchange is not only about the content, but also about the people. If someone is going through difficulties -- and I believe no-one here is a basically bad or anti-social person -- I think we could make some effort and try and be at least tolerant of them.

From my experience, **replying to misbehavior in a supportive and understanding manner will most certainly lead to better behavior**. Those that are aggressive, are aggressive not because of their nature, but because of their current life situation. What they need is not more pressure, more marginalisation, but more acceptance and, to use a strong word, more love.

This should happen behind the scenes, in private messages, not in a place where it will be documented for the user's entire life.

Answer (score 1):

As a moderator on another SE site, let me share some of our experience.

I don't know what user you are talking about. We had a single bad user that caused *lots* of noise and unrest with his personal attacks and complete lack of respect and behavior. There were also massive downvoting sprees but luckily the system detects these automatically and cancels them. Why he contributed anything at all is still a mystery; perhaps he is an eternal troll.

Users were enraged. The wiser, cooler users flagged his posts. Moderators sent him private messages and direct emails to help him recognize the errors in his ways. He only got madder and even more unreasonable, and gravely insulted the moderators.

He was banned for a day and informed that this was a warning shot. Upon his return, he made his wrath felt. He quickly earned a week-long ban, and upon his return promptly earned a month-long ban. After that he forced the moderators to ban him permanently.

Lessons:

- The system catches and corrects voting sprees.
- Some users won't listen to reason.
- A short ban can work as a warning shot.
- Long bans may be necessary.
- **most importantly:** work with the affected users (victims) to avoid escalating the war. Ask them to be wiser and smarter than the troll: **flag for moderator attention - don't respond!**

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do not know whether there were bannings of this user in the past. Perhaps you can talk to @splattne, one of our moderators here. The main problem in my opinion is that people had give up with this user X (he and only he earned all my downvotes). Just a look in the chat or meta shows this. There is talking about user X will be soon alone here and so one. Bad signs, very bad.

Comment: Til today I didn't recognize that the downvotes of user X are purged. Some, not all, of user X comments are deleted after been flagged by other users and me. But some bad flagged comments already exists. This user has had more than one year time to terrorismn this site. He causes that other users are inactive here or leaved completly the site (I can understand them!)! There is no more reason to wait!

Comment: And how would you deal with the offence below the belt? For me only one is enouph to ban him.

Comment: It sounds like he is really making a LOT of trouble. Why haven't you just banned him already? Wait, let's take that in the TL chat, not here!

Answer (score 1):

(English version below the line)

Ich glaube der Versuch meinen Namen nicht zu nennen ist nicht in böser Absicht getroffen worden, aber im Effekt schließt er mich aus der Diskussion aus, wenn ich ihn respektiere, oder zwingt mich zu kuriosen Verrenkungen, wenn ich mich an der Diskussion beteiligen will, und dabei so tue, als ginge es um User allgemein, nicht um mich persönlich.

Nebenbei weiß es sowieso jeder, der ein Suchfeld bedienen kann und das getan hat.

Es wurde auch nicht *mir* angeboten meinen Namen zu nennen, sondern den Moderatoren, die mich auch über den Thread, den ich schon kannte, aber desssen Versuch mich auszuschließen ich anfangs respektiert habe, informierten. Ich habe anfangs der Woche darauf reagiert und seitdem nichts mehr gehört. Heute werde ich vom Threadstarter in einem Kommentar höhnisch mit `Falls doch nenne ich das egozentrisch. Schon die Frage auf Meta (Link) besucht?` provoziert.

Damit ist für mich der Punkt erreicht die Entscheidung den Moderatoren aus der Hand zu nehmen, und in Anspruch zu nehmen was vornehme Tugend im Rechtsstaat ist, das Recht auf Gehör im Verfahren.

Um die Diskussion mit Fakten anzureichern, hier 2 Links, einmal zur [ursprünglichen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1534/266) und einmal zu der bereits geführten [Diskussion auf Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/403/266).

Die Behauptung "We laughed, let's now delete it" sei eine Beleidung ist ein grobes Missverständnis. `We laughed` heißt nicht, `wir lachen über Deine Frage`, noch `wir lachen über Dich`, sondern `wir lachen mit Dir über Deinen Scherz` und ist keine Beleidigung - vor allem nicht unter der Gürtellinie.

Da es mühsam ist die genaue Historie zurückzuverfolgen und nicht offensichtlich ist, inwieweit diese eine Rolle spielt, bitte ich darauf besonders zu achten.

Die Frage wurde am 22. Juni 2011 gestellt, überarbeitet wurde sie nicht etwa 3 Tage später, sondern 3 Tage und ein Jahr, bzw. 1 Jahr minus eine Woche später.

Beantwortet wurde die um 4:05 gestellte Frage von splattne um 6:36 Uhr, der schon erklärte, dass die alternative Erklärung ein Hoax ist. Am selben Tag wurde diese Antwort akzeptiert, die Uhrzeit kann ich nicht feststellen.

Um 8:56 und 11:41 meldete sich Phira mit Kommentaren zur Frage zu Wort, weiter Stupedia eingehend. Darauf reagierte zunächst monatelang niemand.

Man kann zum Glück die ursprüngliche Frage noch inspizieren, als auch die Überschrift, die sie ursprünglich hatte. Dass jmd. eine ungewöhnliche Erklärung findet, diese uns aber nicht präsentiert und auch keinen Link, so dass wir den Kontext zur Beurteilung der Erklärung mit in unsere Beurteilung einfließen lassen können hinterlässt bei mir den Eindruck, dass hier jemand ein Spiel mit uns spielen wollte. Das Spiel hat sich nicht, wie vom Poster erhofft, entwickelt, und so hat er nicht an der Klärung der Fragen, die sich stellten, mitgewirkt. Das ist für mich die einfachste, plausible Erklärung.

Am 15. Juni diesen Jahres schreibt Em1 dann, dass er auch für 'close' voted. Wer diese Diskussion aufgebracht hat kann ich mit meiner Reputation nicht rekonstruieren, wie ich auch nicht mehr weiß, wie sich mein Kommentar genau zeitlich einordnet. Am 22.6. um 4:40 ediert Markus die Frage erstmalig, und um 4:28 erneut. Um 5:45 erstellt er einen Metathread zur Frage und um 8:15 ediert er diesen.

Um 8:36 antwortet darauf Em1, und ich 5 Tage später.

Das interpretiere ich so, dass die 5 Netto-Up-Votes (6x up, 1x down) und deren Reputationspunkte dem Threadersteller so wichtig waren, dass er dann doch die Kritik aufgriff, und versuchte die Frage zu retten.

Ich kann natürlich nicht ausschließen, dass die ursprüngliche Frage eine aufrichtige, naive Frage war, aber wenn ich das annehmen soll, dann muss ich annehmen, dass der Frager aus anderen Gründen erstens den Inhalt der alternativen Erklärung uns vorenthalten hat, zweitens einen anderen Grund hatte, uns den Link vorzuenthalten, wo wir uns hätten informieren können - wer würde das tun, der will, dass wir ihm helfen eine Frage zu klären? Wieso reagiert er dann nicht auf die Kommentare?

Da Teile der Auseinandersetzung jetzt gelöscht sind ist es natürlich schwierig den Konflikt genauer zu rekonstruieren.

Was mir ein Rätsel ist, ist, wie man die Aussage "Wir haben gelacht - nun lasst uns die Frage löschen" als Beleidigung auffassen kann, dazu noch als eine unter der Gürtellinie. Da ich diese Interpretation nicht als meinen Fehler betrachte sehe ich auch keinen Grund um Entschuldigung zu bitten.

---

I guess the attempt to keep my name out of the discussion wasn't made in bad intent, but in effect I am excluded from the discussion, if I respect it, or I'm forced to curious gymnastics, if I try to participate without disclosing the info, an information which everybody who knows how to hande a searchfield, btw.

It wasn't offered to *me*, to disclose the information, but to the moderators, which informed me about the thread, which I already knew, but whichs wish to keep me out I respected in the beginning. I responded to their post in the beginning of the week. Today, the threadstarter provoked me in a comment with `Falls doch nenne ich das egozentrisch. Schon die Frage auf Meta (verlinkt) besucht?` (If though, I call that egocentric. Already visited the question on Meta (linked)?)

At that point I made the decision to participate in this thread and defend myself, which iś a primary rule of law.

To enrich the discussion with facts, here are 2 links, once [to the original question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1534/266) and once to an already held [discussion on meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/403/266).

The assertion "We laughed, let's now delete it" would ber an insult is a big misunderstanding. `We laughed` doesn't mean `we laugh about your question`, nor `we laughed about you`, but `we laugh with you about your joke` and isn't an insult, especially not below someones belt.

I want you, readers, to spend special attention to the timeline of the events.

The question was posted on June, 22. 2011, edited not 3 days later, but one year + 3 days later, respectively one year  minus one week.

The 4:05 asked question was answered by splattne at 6:36, who already mentioned that there is a hoax, running around. I don't know and which time, but this answer was accepted at the same day.

At 8:56 and 11:41, Phira commented to the question mentioning Stupedia. Nobody reacted on this for months.

Luckily, the original question can be investigated. That somebody finds a curious explanation but doesn't tell us which, not providing the link, where we would see the context, made me think, that this is an joke, an entertainment question, which didn't work as expected. Since markus didn't help to answer the comments this was the most plausible explanation for me.

At the 15th of June this year Em1 writes, that he is *too* in favor for closing the question. Who initiated this discussion is not viewable with my reputation, and I don't see at which time exactly my comment in question was made - it was about then, June 2011, I guess. At 6.22 at 4:40 Markus edited the  question for the first time, at 4:28 a second time. At 5:45 he created the thread on meta about the question and at 8:15 he edited this one.

At 8:36 Em1 answered, and me 5 days later.

So I think the sum of 5 up votes (6x up, 1x down) and their reputation points where important for the threaderstarter, so he finally reacted to the critic and tried to resque the question.

I can't exclude that the original question was a serious but naive one, but then I have to ask, why the asker didn't respond to the comments, but responded quickly to the close attemps one year later. Why didn't he reveal until today, where he found the alternative explanation? He not even confirmed, that this story was the one he found.

Since parts of the discussion are deleted it is hard to reconstruct it precisely.

But I don't understand how my remark "Wir haben gelacht - nun lasst uns die Frage löschen" (we laughed, now let's delete it) can be read as an insult; more so: below the belt. 
Since I don't think that the misinterpretation is my fault, I don't see reason to beg for pardon.

Comment: Eine Anmerkung meinerseits: Das Closen einer Frage beeinflusst nicht die Rep, die durch diese Frage oder evnt. Antworten erwirtschaftet wurde.

Answer (score 1):

(English version in lower half below the line.)

Neben dem konkreten Vorwurf der Beleidigung muss ich mich noch gegen den vagen Vorwurf überhaupt ein unangenehmer Zeitgenosse zu sein, der weggehört, verteidigen.

Dies ist insofern schwierig, als dieser Vorwurf so vage ist. Es ist der Versuch aus vielen, unbewiesenen Vorwürfen einen die Schlußfolgerung abzuleiten, dass der Vorwurf selbst stimmt, und gar nicht belegt werden muss, da doch die Vielzahl der Vorwürfe die Richtigkeit beweist.

Ohne einen Link zum jeweiligen Vorwurf kann ich mich natürlich überhaupt nicht verteidigen, und wahrscheinlich ist das der zugrundeliege Grund, wieso es keinen Link gibt: Die Vorwürfe sind konkret alle nicht haltbar - es ist blos ein Gefühl.

```
How to deal with such a (over long time) misbehaving (dogmatic, pedantic, petty, polemic, insulting, educating other people, systematic downvoting) user?
```

Systematisches Downvoting - welche Systemtik wird hier behauptet, und inwiefern ist das problematisch. Ich habe bei über 1000 Votes 1/4 Downvotes. Damit habe ich 750*(5 bis 10) und 250*-2 Reputationspunkte über die User gebracht, also rund 5000 Reputationspunkte plus.

Da ich downvotes meist begründe, upvotes jedoch selten, mag der Eindruck entstehen, dass ich ein negativ gestimmter Zeitgenosse bin. Wenn es zum Disput kommt bin ich außerdem beharrlich. Dazu gehört jedoch auch immer ein zweiter - möglicherweise hat ja auch dieser die schlechteren Argumente? Das zu überprüfen geht freilich nur, wenn man den jeweiligen Fall anschaut.

`Educating` zu sein kann ja nicht ernsthaft ein Vorwurf sein, oder? Man ist hier um sich gegenseitig zu unterrichten und sich unterrichten zu lassen - was sonst will man hier?

Beleidigungen sind nicht mein Stil. Du wirst hier keine Beleidigung von mir finden.

Polemik: Stimmt.

Pedanterie stimmt nicht. Ich bin genau und beharrlich, aber nicht kleinlich. Ich versuche mich schon auf die Thematik zu beziehen, und nicht Kommafehler zu diskutieren, die nicht zum Thema gehören. Wo bitte, bin ich pedantisch?

Kleinkariert - dito.

Dogmatisch. Hm. Welches Dogma verfolge ich denn? Der Inhalt der Seite ist ja oft die richtige Formulierung, Schreibweise, Beugung und Deklination von Wörtern, Formulierungen und Sätzen. Ohne ein gewisses Maß an Genauigkeit wird der Sinn der Seite verfehlt. Ich orientiere mich hier etwa an der Ausrichtung von stackoverflow.com: Die Antwort muss richtig sein, sie muss sich auf die Frage beziehen, und sie sollte bei vielen möglichen Antworten zu den besseren gehören.

Auf stackoverflow wird auch diskutiert, ob für eine Fragestellung ein Array angemessen ist, ob ein Algorithmus skaliert, ob unportabler Code vorgestellt wird und so wird versucht eine Antwort zu verbessern.

Wenn Kommentare nicht als Ermunterung aufgefasst werden, die Antwort oder Frage zu überdenken und zu verbessern, dann ist das nicht meine Entscheidung.

---

Beneath the concrete accusation of making an insult I have to defend against the vaguely allegation of being an unfriendly user per se, who should be banned.

That's a problematic job, since there are a lot of accusations, but they are not very concrete. Instead, there are much accusations, and imho to replace the quality of the critic by quantity.

Without link to an event under critic, I can't defend against it, and I suspect, that that is the reason for not providing any link.

```
How to deal with such a (over long time) misbehaving (dogmatic, pedantic, petty, polemic, insulting, educating other people, systematic downvoting) user?
```

Systematisches Downvoting - which system is meant, and what's the problem? I left more than 1000 votes, 1/4 of them downvotes. Thereby I produced 750*(5 or 10) and 250*-2 reputation points for the users, so about 5000 in total positive.

Since I explain most of my downvotes, but upvotes rarely, the impression might arise, that I'm a negatively mooded person. If a debat arises, then I am in good condition - yes, I don't give up that easily. But for an argument, you always need two persons. Maybe this other person has the bad arguments? Of course, to decide this question you need to look at the concrete case. We need links.

To be `educating` can't be a reasonable critic on this site, can it? Aren't we here to teach each other and to get teached? What else is your reason to visit GL&U?

Insults aren't part of my style. You won't find any insult from me here.

Polemik: That's right.

Pedantic is not true. I'm precise and persistent, but not pedantic or petty. I always try to be on topic, and not to discuss smaller mistakes which are off topic. Where do you see pedantic behaviour?

Dogmatic? Which dogma did you mention? Since the theme of this site is correct spelling, grammer, wording, usage of time and so on: Without a certain amount of precision the intent of the site is missed. I orient myself here at the policy on stackoverflow.com: The answer has to be right, has to be on topic, and should be, if there is more than one possible solution, be one of the better ones.

On stackoverflow there are discussions in the comments too, whether an answer should use an array for the solution or a list, whether an algorithmus scales, is the code portable. Comments can help to improve an answer and to remove mistakes or not so good recommendations.

If comments aren't understood as hint, how to improve a question or answer, then this is not my decision.